# Android Widget: setSelection on ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

So I'm developing my first Android Widget, consisting primarily of a `ListView`. I'm using a `RemoteViewsFactory` to populate the list view, which works fine, but I'm having trouble defaulting the selected index of the  list.

Normally `ListView#setSelection` works fine, but in this case (using `RemoteViews`) it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I'm sure this is the wrong place to be doing it, but in `AppWidgetProvider#onUpdate` I'm doing the following:

```
 RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
 widget.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list, svcIntent);

 Log.i(TAG, "Setting selection: " + position);
 widget.setInt(R.id.widget_list, "setSelection", position);
```

I'm assuming it's not working because the list hasn't been populated yet, due to the async nature of collection views, but I'm not sure where else I can even put it.

The goal is that the first time the user sees the widget, before interacting with it, and any time the list changes (hourly), the list is scrolled to a specific item.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

widget.setScrollPosition(R.id.widget_list, position);

Comment: You should expand on this answer a little. Single lines of code, while correct are not usually hugely helpful to the OP.